# Sort a sublist prolog

Tags: sorting, prolog, sublist

I have this list in Prolog:

[[13,Audi A3,11.11.2011,75000,berlina,audi,12100,verde pisello,[4wd],3.0000133333333334],[11,santafe,11.11.2011,80000,fuoristrada,audi,2232232,verde pisello,[Metalizzata,Sedile in Pelle,4wd],7.0000125]]|

I want to sort this list for last value of sublist, as example I want to have this result:

[[11,santafe,11.11.2011,80000,fuoristrada,audi,2232232,verde pisello,[Metalizzata,Sedile in Pelle,4wd],*7.0000125*],[13,Audi A3,11.11.2011,75000,berlina,audi,12100,verde pisello,[4wd],*3.0000133333333334*]]

Comment: You should make your question more abstract, for example use the list: [[a,[b],1],[p,[q],3]]

Answer (score 1):

[predsort](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=predsort/3) it's your friend. Then sort is easy, but to sell an Audi `verde pisello` will remain very, very hard...

```
sort_on_last(List, Sorted) :-
    predsort(compare_last, List, Sorted).

compare_last(R, X, Y) :-
    last(X, Xl),
    last(Y, Yl),
    compare(R, Xl, Yl).
```

To try it:

```
test :- sort_on_last(
        [[11,santafe,'11.11.2011',80000,fuoristrada,audi,2232232,'verde pisello',['Metalizzata','Sedile in Pelle','4wd'],7.0000125],
         [13,'Audi A3','11.11.2011',75000,berlina,audi,12100,'verde pisello',['4wd'],3.0000133333333334]
        ], S),
    maplist(writeln, S).
?- test.
[13,Audi A3,11.11.2011,75000,berlina,audi,12100,verde pisello,[4wd],3.0000133333333334]
[11,santafe,11.11.2011,80000,fuoristrada,audi,2232232,verde pisello,[Metalizzata,Sedile in Pelle,4wd],7.0000125]
true.
```

A particularity of predsort/3: it acts as sort/2, thus **remove** duplicates.
To avoid this problem, compare_last/3 can be changed, avoiding return **=**, in this way:

```
compare_last(R, X, Y) :-
    last(X, Xl),
    last(Y, Yl),
    ( Xl < Yl -> R = (<) ; R = (>) ).
```

Comment: hehheh owever i not have only 2 sublist. I want to sort by last value of each sublist  [[13,Audi A3,11.11.2011,75000,berlina,audi,12100,verde pisello,[4wd],3.0296266666666667],[15,Fiat Punto JTD,10.1.2007,201000,berlina,fiat,4000,verde pisello,[],1.0110547263681593],[16,Peugeot 106,1.3.1998,230000,citycar,peugeot,1700,nero lucido,[],0.009660869565217391],[18,Tata safari,10.1.1989,110000,fuoristrada,tata,2000,verde oliva,[4wd],0.0202],[11,santafe,11.11.2011,80000,fuoristrada,hynaday,14000,verde pisello,[Metalizzata,Sedile in Pelle,4wd],5.027775]

Comment: swap the < to > in compare_last. I'm sorry I understood you want increasing prices...